# Unresolved external symbol _IID / _CLSID

Tags: c++, atl

I created a default ATL project with MSVC 2010 with a simple default ATL dialog. Then I added the second project into solution, named MyControls, where I created ATL DHTML Control with a help of Wizard. Then I placed ATL DHTML Control to ATL dialog.

Now I would like to call some methods of that ATL DHTML Control in ATL dialog's `OnInitDialog` function. In order to be able to make a call like:

```
CComPtr<IDHTMLControl> ptr;
HRESULT hr = GetDlgControl(IDC_ACTIVEX_CONTROL_DHTML
    , IID_IDHTMLControl, (void**)&ptr);
```

I am including the file DHTMLControl.h from MyControls project. However, I get the following errors:

- Error    1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDHTMLControl
- Error    2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _LIBID_MyControlsLib
- Error    3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_DHTMLControl
- Error    4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDHTMLControlUI

Note: It appears that I am linking MyControls.lib incorrectly, however, I added MyControls.lib to Linker->Input->Additonal Dependencies & specified ../$(Configuration) in the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is related to how you link one project with the other. There is something missing here and since you don't show the code, it's a pure guess only.

On control project you have a type library which, when being built, also generates files `MyControls_i.h`, `MyControls_i.c`, `MyControls_p.c`. I suppose that on the application project you included `_i.h` file which declared symbols as externals, and you did not include the `_i.c` file with symbols actually defined.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right - the generated _i.h/c must be included. I was going to add own answer but you had already done that. Thank you!

Comment: how do you include these files? if I add them to the project I get errors with PCH....

Comment: You don't have to add them to the project, C++ code `#include` is just fine.